# What is the default behaviour on a wx.EVT_ACTIVATE event in a windows wxwidgets application

Tags: wxwidgets

Or more specifically, what are the consequences of catching this in my main form and stopping propagation to the parents.

Background: I have a bug (which I suspect is arising from the wxwidgets framework) which manifests when unfocusing and then refocusing the application. Catching this event seems to fix the bug.

Comment: what is the bug? how it manifests itself? what did you put inside the handler? It is perfectly legal to consume any event, but for non-wxCommandEvent you should really know what you are doing.

Comment: The bug affects the wx.ScrolledWindow. If you click just to the right of the thumb bar (on a vertical left scroll bar) the windows scrolls to the top (sometimes). If you then scroll away from the top and select another application (eg chrome) and then go back to the wxwidgets app the scroll bar always goes back to the top.

Comment: The handler is empty.

Comment: which wx version? which platform? can you reproduce it in a sample or with very minimal sample modification? can you also try with the latest sources of the library?

Comment: The question wasn't really supposed concern the bug. I'm just trying to get a quick fix in and don't plan on any version upgrades. :)

Comment: ok I understand. If it works, then everything is good. it just a very weird fix. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't consume `wxEVT_ACTIVATE`, e.g. under MSW this means that your program would return 0 when handling `WM_ACTIVATE` which would prevent the code in `DefWindowProc()` for handling this message from executing. I don't know what exactly are the consequences of doing this, but I'd expect problems with the window active status not being updated correctly.

Even if doing this "works" for you, it seems very wrong to compensate a bug with another bug.

Comment: Thanks. If it "works" for me I'm happy with the fix. But you've given me some pointers for further investigation. Sometimes in software it's OK to compensate a bug with another bug if there is a complete understanding and there isn't time for a full fix. I don't have a complete understanding, hence the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what causes the original bug. As always, if you think it's a bug in wxWidgets, please submit the simplest possible patch to the wxWidgets minimal sample allowing to reproduce the problem to [wx bug tracker](https://trac.wxwidgets.org)

Comment: Thanks VZ. It may not be worth it. The version I'm using is years old.